# ValueError: URL must include a 'scheme', 'host', and 'port' component

Tags: elasticsearch, pycharm

Trying to use elastic search for a project.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://example.com",
    http_auth=("abc", "bcd"),
)
```

But getting the error:

```
ValueError: URL must include a 'scheme', 'host', and 'port' component (ie 'https://localhost:9200')
```

I am running this on Pycharm CE and have created a Virtual Environment of Python 3.9 .
Should I be using a different version of Python to make this work??
Moreover, I have already tried `pip install acryl-datahub[datahub-rest,elasticsearch]==0.8.27.1` but to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same error. Installing ES version 7.17 solved the problem. I was also getting a not available on `pip install acryl-datahub[datahub-rest,elasticsearch]==0.8.27.1`. Tried with the next one available (0.8.28.0) and realized it was downgrading `elasticsearch` to 7.17.

So try `pip install elasticsearch==7.17`.

Answer (score 0):

Using these lines of code in *settings.py* helped me to avoid this error.

```
ELK_BASE_URL = 'elasticsearch://{username}:{password}@{host_ip}:{host_port}'
ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = ELK_BASE_URL.format(
    username='ELASTICSEARCH_USER',
    password='ELASTICSEARCH_PASS',
    host_ip='elasticsearch', # 'elasticsearch' - service name in docker-compose.yml
    host_port='9200'
)
    
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': [ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL]
    },
}
```

Or you can use just:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
        'default': {
            'hosts': 'http://elasticsearch:9200' # same as above
        },
}
```

p.s. you can also try it with 'localhost' instead of 'elasticsearch'.